# Restrict Type variable to specific class or subclass

Tags: c#, types, factory

I'm working in C# and would like to store a type on my class, but I want that type to be of either a certain class, or subclass of it.

This might be what the code looks like:

```
public class Factory
{

    public Type typeToInstantiate where Type: ABaseType;

    public Factory(Type instantiateThis where Type : ABaseType)
    {
        this.typeToInstantiate = instantiateThis;
    }

    public void DoTheThing()
    {
        var newObj = (ABaseType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInstantiate);
        newObj.PrintSomethingToConsole();
    }
}


public abstract class ABaseType
{
    public abstract void PrintSomethingToConsole();
}

public abstract class ASubType : ABaseType
{
    public override void PrintSomethingToConsole()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Something");
    }
}

public abstract class AnotherSubType : ABaseType
{
    public override void PrintSomethingToConsole()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Something else");
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Factory> factories = new List<Factory>();
    factories.Add(new Factory(typeof(AnotherSubType)));
    factories.Add(new Factory(typeof(ASubType)));

    foreach (var factory in factories) factory.PrintSomethingToConsole();
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve (in case someone has a better idea): I'm creating a kind of factory that will instantiate some number of objects of the specified type. So, when this factory is created, it will be created with a type that it should instantiate. However, this factory has a specific purpose, so it should only be instantiating objects of a specific class (or a subclass of that class).

Comment: Normally this is handled using generic type constraints...

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking for here. Seems like you are describing the abstract factory design pattern, but you don't want the factory to be abstract. Does that seems about right to you?

Comment: My problem with this is that it will cause factories wrapping different types to themselves be different types.

Comment: If you want a factory that can handle any type, you want `class Factory<T>`.  If you want a class that can handle any type that descends from a given base class you want `class Factory<T> where T: BaseClass`, per @Blindy's solution.  If you want to define this subclass at runtime, your validation can only occur at runtime.

Comment: The base class and any subclasses of it will be defined at compile time. When instantiating this factory, the caller should specify what Type it should be creating. However, that should create a compile-time error if that Type does not inherit from a specific class (defined by the factory).

Comment: It seems that @Blindy's solution is what you need - you can use the generic contraint at the class level or at the method level

Comment: Added an example, check my code

Comment: I still don't understand why you think a generic constraint is not solving your problem. Seems to me like using a generic method with a constraint will give you exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: That would require the caller to know what type the factory should instantiate. But that should be data the factory holds.

Comment: @PaulRJones Didn't you write this in your previous comment: "When instantiating this factory, the caller should specify what Type it should be creating."? How can the caller specify what type to instantiate and at the same time not know what type the factory should instantiate?

Comment: I'm afraid neither of us is able to understand what you need. Add the method signature to your factory method with proper C# syntax - what type of object to return, and what parameters should it receive

Comment: In other words, what is the caller sending to the factory (parameter)? And what should the factory return? A `Type` object or an instance of something?

Comment: After trying to understand every OP's comments I think this question is a bit unclear. If `the caller should specify what Type it should be creating.` then Blindy's answer should be marked as accepted answer, I think.

Comment: The creator of the factory, and the caller of the factories instantiation method will be different entities.

Comment: Sorry to be the one that put the final nail in the coffin, but this question doesn't seem to be salvageable. I think we've given enough time and effort on this.

Comment: "The creator of the factory, and the caller of the factories instantiation method will be different entities." That should have been stated in the question in the first place. Also the fact that you want to put different factories inside a collection. You are looking for the [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) - it will solve all the problems you mentioned.

Comment: @PaulRJones I just took a look into your last edit. IMO you could (and should!) definitely do what you need with generics.

Comment: @ZoharPeled While I appreciate the effort you've put in to this, I don't appreciate that you're calling it a lost cause. By doing so, you are preventing someone who might be able to help/understand from looking at this. If you are frustrated by solving this, I would ask that you simple leave it be, as marking it unsolvable only hurts my chances of finding help.

Comment: @RuiJarimba Is there a way to do this, and still have multiple factories (that will wrap different types) in the same collection? If so, that 100% solves my problem.

Comment: @PaulRJones I was the last of 5 different people voting to close this problem, all of us, by the way, voted on the same option - "unclear what you're asking". Before I voted to close, I've watched other people posting answers and comments, and posted comments myself on both the question and some of it's answers. I think I've done all I can before voting to close this question.

Comment: Since I think I finally figured out what is it that you need, I've created a code example on Rextester for you to look at - [The abstract factory design pattern implemented in c# using generics](https://rextester.com/PNPH34293) If that is what you need, let me know and I'll vote to reopen (and hopefully can post that as an answer).

Comment: I encountered similar desire few times. What I ended up with is creation of base class or interface for factory products, let's call it IFactoryProduct and then inside Factory I am implementing method "static IFactoryProduct Produce(Type exactType)", yes it would be cool to ensure that this Type passed as argument could be checked in compile time, but then this restriction must be ensured in compile time and can not accept data (user created or auto generated). So if you want type argument come from data, not from code, then you must ensure correct type kind on parsing data stage.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking about something like this:

```
class C<T> where T: SomeBaseClass
{
}
```

Comment: Not really, though I have considered something similar. If I were to use this approach, a C<Int32> object and a C<String> object would be of different types, which I don't want. I want the "factories" to be of the same type.

Comment: But `string` and `int` are different types... their closest common ancestor is `object`....

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @PaulRJones I'm not sure I follow, you want to have one factory type holding multiple kinds of objects? Are you then asking how to store unrelated objects in one list, while only allowing a certain base class independent of some generic type on the factory? The answer to the latter is `List<object>`, and check the type in your `Add` function.

Comment: I've added a short snippet that I'm hoping explains what I'm looking for better.

Comment: If you're holding the type to instantiate as a variable, both storing a type there and instantiating them happen at runtime, so only at runtime can you check for your constraints. So again, add whatever checks you need in the setter of that `Type` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Type`'s`IsAssignableFrom` in your logic if you need to check this at runtime.  e.g.

```
public class MyFactory
{
    Type baseType = typeof(MyBaseType);
    IDictionary<string, Type> typeMap = new Dictionary<string, Type>() {}
    public void RegisterType(string typeName, Type type) 
    {
        if (!(type == baseType || baseType.IsAssignableFrom(type)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(type));
        typeMap.Add(typeName, type);    
    }
}
```

For a more detailed example, see my code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53121973/361842

Comment: I've considered this as well, but the problem is that the error would be runtime and not compile time.

Comment: For runtime I think that your only option is to go with generics per Amy's comment / Blindy's answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53124955/361842

Answer (score 0):

Given the following classes:

```
public abstract class ABaseType
{
    public abstract void PrintSomethingToConsole();
}

public class ASubType : ABaseType
{
    public override void PrintSomethingToConsole()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Something");
    }
}

public class AnotherSubType : ABaseType
{
    public override void PrintSomethingToConsole()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Something else");
    }
}
```

(Quick note: classes AnotherSubType and ASubType cannot be abstract if you want to create instances of them).

Your factory can be refactored like this:

```
public class Factory 
{
    private readonly List<ABaseType> _instances;

    public Factory()
    {
        _instances = new List<ABaseType>();
    }

    public void Register<T>()  where T : ABaseType, new()
    {
        // creates a new instance of the object
        // As an alternative, save the type and create a new instance in DoTheThing()
        var instance = new T();
        _instances.Add(instance);
    }

    public void DoTheThing()
    {
        _instances.ForEach(x => x.PrintSomethingToConsole());
    }
}
```

Using the code:

```
var factory = new Factory();
factory.Register<AnotherSubType>();
factory.Register<ASubType>();

factory.DoTheThing();
```

Output:

> Something else
>
> Something

Comment: The problem with the first solution is that it cannot exist in a collection with factories that generate a different type. The problem with the second solution is that it requires the caller of CreateFruit to know the type that it should instantiate.

Comment: @PaulRJones I'm afraid I have absolutely no idea what you need. Maybe you should add some code to show how the factories are used.

Comment: @PaulRJones This seems more and more like an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think it's time to seat back and think about the problem you want to solve (using the factory) instead of how to implement the factory itself. Perhaps the entire approach is wrong and a factory is not what you need at all - or perhaps the problem is not with the factory class, but with other parts of the software.

Comment: @ZoharPeled well said

Comment: This is why I described the problem I was trying to solve as well as how I was trying to solve it.

Comment: @PaulRJones edited my answer

Comment: It's not a factory, it's a flywheel.

Answer (score -1):

I understand your requirements as follow:

1. You want a class that can contain other types, restricted to subclasses of BaseType, that is type-safe.
2. Different instances of this class must be capable of being stored in a variable of the same type.

You can do this with covariance and type constraints.

Declare the covariant interface:

```
public interface IMyFactory<out T>
{
    T Resolve();
}
```

Implement it in your class:

```
public class MyFactory<T> : IMyFactory<T> where T :BaseType, new()
{
    public readonly Type typeToInstantiate;

    public MyFactory()
    {
        typeToInstantiate = typeof(T);
    }

    public T Resolve()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IMyFactory<BaseType> factory;
        {
            factory = new MyFactory<BaseType>();
            var instance = factory.Resolve();
            Console.WriteLine(instance.GetType().FullName);
        }
        {
            factory = new MyFactory<DerivedType>() as IMyFactory<BaseType>;
            var instance = factory.Resolve();
            Console.WriteLine(instance.GetType().FullName);
        }

    }
}
```

Notice there is only one variable declared here, but it can contain either type of factory, and each factory will resolve to is proper type at run-time, as shown in the output.

Output:

```
Example.BaseType
Example.DerivedType
```

Here is a [link to a DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7C1nal) for the above.

Comment: This would store an object. I want to store a type.

Comment: Please see my revised answer.